# Sum and product over interval in R

Tags: r, sum

I am trying to implement the following simple formulas in R:

- **Formula 1:**

[image]

I have no idea how to implement in R the product operator when the limits of the interval are very large (e.g. value of the upper limit = 10,000 instead of 5)

- **Formula 2**

[image]

Example input for second formula (in reality, the dimension of the interval S is much much bigger)

```
 S = list(c(1,0,0), c(0,1,0), c(0,0,1))
 X = c(1,2,3)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In my real example yes, but not here. The data involved in my real example is huge, and the example here is not really representative of var-cov matrix, as the dimensions of X and gamma aren't appropriate.

Comment: Then you can use `cov` for the real data if you are actually looking for that.

Comment: I will need to implement that formula outside of the `cov` context, so I would need a more general formula.

Comment: IN your example, S is an array? I can't reproduce your data

Comment: It's a list: just edited my post.

Comment: Please post the expected output for your example. Isn't it possible to unlist and then convert the elements into matrix and do `%*%`?

Comment: Thanks Metrics, but I need to do the cross-product using EACH element in S at a time.@Dwin perfectly addressed the issue here. Thanks for trying! I give you +1 for the log idea.

Comment: @Mariam Formula 1 is simply `(1+x)^sum(1:5)`. Is that correct? Don't you mean the sum instead of product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first formula it has been mentioned that it is better to do this on the log scale, if your true values of x are near 0 then the `log1p` function may be of help.

In general for these types of problems you can use `lapply` or `sapply` to compute the pieces that need to be multiplied or summed (or whatever), then use `sum` or `prod` to sum, multiply.  If you want to collapse/combine the values with an operator that does not have a nice function like `sum` or `prod` then use the `Reduce` function.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, take the log:

```
i *log(1+x)
```

For the second formula: (not clear what is the expected output)

```
ss<-matrix(unlist(S), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
X<-as.matrix(X)
crossprod(crossprod(X,ss),t(X))

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Comment: That solves (somewhat) my first issue. Any thoughts about the second?

Comment: Are you computing variance covariance matrix in second formula?

Comment: Hold on, when taking `logs` of a multiplicative function you should sum and then `exp` the result. So it should be (if `x <- 3` and `i <- 1:3`... `exp( sum( log( ( 1 + x ) ^ i ) ) )` which will give the same as `prod( ( 1 + x ) ^ i )`

Comment: @ Simon0101 : yes, you have to do that. I skipped that.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe more compactly:

First formula:

```
function(n, x) exp(sum(seq_len(n)*log(1+x)))
```

Second formula:

```
function(X, S) rowSums(sapply(S, function(y) sum(X*y)*X ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 S = list c((1,0,0), c(0,1,0), c(0,0,1))
 X = c(1,2,3)

 lapply( lapply(S, function(x) X %*% x %*% t(X) ) , sum)
[[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]]
[1] 12

[[3]]
[1] 18
```